# Convert Expression<Func<TEntity,TKey> to Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>

Tags: c#, expression

I'm looking to convert `Expression<Func<TEntity,TKey>` to `Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>`

Being that everything is an object, I tried an implicit cast like so:

```
var propertyMetadata = 
    new PropertyMetadata<TEntity>((Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>)expression);
```

However that creates an error:

> Cannot Convert Type `Expression<Func<TEntity,TKey>` to `Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>`

Is there an easy way to convert between these two types

Comment: That involves creating a brand new expression, it's a bit complicated if `TKey` can be a value type. But if possible, I'd say `PropertyMetadata` should have a way to allow construction from a `Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>>`. Is this a class of your own? If so, is it open for modification?

Comment: @hvd it can't take in the tkey type because it's a whitelist of properties searchable in a type. So there a multiple types of tkey.  When I write it by hand it automatically creates a concert in my expression

Comment: I understand that. But you can have a private constructor taking `Expression expression` invoked by a generic `PropertyMetadata<TEntity>.Create<TKey>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> expression)`. This allows multiple property types for the same `PropertyMetadata<TEntity>`.

Comment: Yes but even with the constructor I still need to do the cast since the expression is in a variable

Comment: Eh? I'm proposing `var propertyMetadata = PropertyMetadata<TEntity>.Create(expression);`, no cast needed since it would take in the expression directly.

Comment: How will that work? You will either need to add a generic constraint to property metadata representing its key TKey which then you won't be able to store different types in a dictionary, or alternatively you will need to do the cast inside of the create method?

Comment: All `Expression<TDelegate>` classes derive from the non-generic `Expression` class, so I suggested to forward to a non-generic constructor and operating on the base class. Depending on what `PropertyMetadata<TEntity>`'s constructor does with the expression, other options could be better.

Comment: @hvd oh sorry I totally misunderstood, that will probably work,  but I would rather maintain the safety of knowing my expression originates from the proper type etc

Comment: I probably can do this the long way and just call a concert on the body of the expression but I'm looking for a simple cast

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple extension method to do so,  It's not long I was just thinking there was a simpler way to cast

```
public static Expression<Func<TInput, object>> ToObjectExpression<TInput, TOutput>
                                       (this Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> expression)
{
    Expression converted = Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, object>>(converted, expression.Parameters);
}
```